# "IS A", "HAS A" relationship design decision

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a board and the board has moving tiles.
It is pretty straight forward that my model will have a Board class and a Tile class what are POCOs and Board "has" tiles (Board has an IList <Tile>)

I have a UI (Unity3d behaviour) Say BoardBehaviour "has a" Board. But here starts my problem. I also have TileBehaviour UI object which "has a" Tile. This seems to be redundant because:

- BoardBehaviour has a Board which has Tiles.
- BoardBehaviour has TileBehaviours (IList<TileBehaviours>) and each TileBehavious has a Tile.

I am a bit confused...

Any ideas how to connect the model and the actual UI classes?

Comment: Is this related to C#, to Java or to class design only?

Comment: class design only, I use csharp/java terminology. Actually the program will be in Csharp but I do not think it matters

Comment: The only Java *terminology* was POJO. Removed Java from the question.

Comment: Why doesn't `Board` has a `BoardBehaviour` and `Tile` has a `TileBehaviour`?

Comment: Isn't this is heavily related with unity? I don't think you'll need complex behavior class in pure C# language only.

Comment: Fendy, the question has nothing to do with Unity.

Answer (score 1):

is a relationship:  when you inherit from base class, the derived class is a baseclass; i.e A car is a vehicle;

has a relationship: when you say the class have something (composition) i.e the car has a engine.
The engine is part of the car.

So here moving Tile is part of board. so the Board "has a" Tile.

when you implement the behaviour (Inherit property) its "is a" relationship. ther is no redundancy.

```
 BoardBehaviour "has a" Board.
```

Board has the board behaviour.

**Board class implements BoardBehaviour. 
Tile class implements TileBehaviour.
Board class's inner class in Tile (or you can create new Tile object in Board if Tile is needed as seperate class).**

Comment: OP's not confused with the terms, is asking about how to solve this class design problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, BoardBehaviour and TileBehaviour are bad classes. Let's analyze current situation. BoardBehaviour has Board. That is strange. In fact, Board should have behaviour. That's why I can propose to create base class BehaviourItem, that will have all the behaviour functionality. Board and Tile should be inherited from BehaviourItem. That should solve some complexity problems.

Answer (score 0):

*Has A*

A Board has Tiles.  A BoardBehavior has TileBehaviors

Here's a theoretical constructor:

```
BoardBehavior(Board board, ...)
{
    this.m_tileBehavoirs = board.Tiles
        .Select(tile => new TileBehavior(tile, ...)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a way to support the proposed design, but OP's asking about the class design.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Strange.  This is the OP question `Any ideas how to connect the model and the actual UI classes?`

Comment: Check the title: *“IS A”, “HAS A” relationship design decision*. Well, I agree that OP confuses us with the real question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this: you should have Two interfaces 1. BoardBehavior 2. TilesBehavior. Implement them in Class Board and Tiles respectively. Now, Board should have List of Tiles. This problem can be solved by Association or Composition. I would suggest you should association. Which means in your Board class lets have a reference of List of Tiles which implement only TilesBehavior. I Hope I am not sounding too complex here. Let me know if I am, I will present a code for this approach to make it more clear.

Comment: I would suggest adding some basic examples and formatting your answer using the formatting techniques provided.